# Duplicate value save

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have this code on `save_post` action:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'product_price_changes' );

function product_price_changes( $post_id ) {

$post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

if ( 'product' == $post_type ) {

    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );

    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision ) {
        return;
    }

    $regular_changes = get_post_meta ($post_id,'regular_changes',true);

    $regular_changes[] = array('test',35000);

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'regular_changes', $regular_changes );

    }
}
```

I want to add an array to the existing array, every time any product is saved.

But with this code every time array is added 2 times to the older array.

Comment: Your action save_post if being fired twice.  Check for the existence of the array element value before adding it to the post meta data field.

Comment: how can i check this?

Comment: Add some debugging to the function => error_log('My message');  which will write a line to your debug.log file.  Then you will see if it's being executed twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can apply if condition to avoid redundancy in the array.
```

I have modified your code. Please use it, I hope it will work as you requested.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'product_price_changes' );

function product_price_changes( $post_id ) {

$post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

if ( 'product' == $post_type ) {

    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );

    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision ) {
        return;
    }

    $regular_changes = get_post_meta ($post_id,'regular_changes',true);
    $new_array = array('test',35000);
    $temp = 0;
    foreach($regular_changes as $changes){
    if(is_array($changes)){
    if(count(array_intersect($new_array, $changes)) == count($new_array)){
        $temp = 1;
        break;
     }
    }       
 }
    if($temp == 0){
       $regular_changes[] = $new_array;
    }

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'regular_changes', $regular_changes );

    }
}
```

Comment: You've got the parameters around the wrong way.  It should be if(!array_diff($regular_changes,$new_array))
Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

Comment: okay, but I have checked it, it's working fine at localhost machine, Thanks

Comment: Read the documentation for the function http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Thank you bro  :)

Comment: don't work.  just add first new array and if if change new array values, don't add to $regular_changes any more!!
$new_array values change every time...

Comment: @Ali, I have just updated the answer, Please updated answer now.

Comment: don't work too! when $new_array is array('test',35000) it work and this array add to meta but next time i change $new_array to array('test',36000). it is diffrent from first array but not added to post meta!

Comment: Okay, Let me check

Comment: @Ali, I have updated and tested the code with scenarios. It's working fine. Actual issue with original array. The original is the array of array. so that array_intersect was not working properly. Now I have put the loop for the original array. It's cool.

Comment: @Ali, Have checked it?

Comment: @Ali, Specially I did it for you bro :)